# How to get Server IP Adress? Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

im noob on this. Sorry, how i can get the current IP adress of the server im connected?
Specific host: agar,io.
Like this:

### [image: Clic]

It show on the placeholder, the ip im connected (As you can see in console, it will display on the placeholder.)

[Script Link - Tampermonkey](http://pastebin.com/PbyLavQe)

Is in coffeescript, i want to show the IP Adress im connected as you can see in the console (specific: Agar.io)
Please, is for editing that script and making it better. Thx.

Comment: You should share your code in the post and not from an off-site link. It would be better also to share only the part that concern your problem so people can help you.

Comment: it seems not to be a java but a javascript question. So update your tag and your question.

Comment: You aren't 'connected' to a server generally beyond the amount of time it takes to get back the asset you requested (there are exceptions). Why do you want to know the IP? That information isn't generally available at the javascript level.